# Image classification exception - InvalidArgumentError of the given labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am doing my research in Skin Cancer Image classification. My dataset consists of images from three classes. I have given labels for each class  as 0,1 and 2.
0 - 1st class image
1= 2nd class image
2 = 3rd class image
While I am compiling my model I am getting an error which is really bugging me. The error that I am getting is -

> > tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 2 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 0 2 2 0 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 1

The code that I am using for compiling the model is -

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),metrics=['acc'])
```

Can somebody please point me to the error I am doing??

> > EDIT 1 : 
> >     my model code is -

```
from keras.applications import InceptionResNetV2
conv_base = InceptionResNetV2(weights = 'imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(150,150,3))
from keras import layers
from keras import models

model=models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Please include the model code.

Comment: You must use OHE (one hot encoding).

Comment: Added the model code as you said - @Matias Valdenegro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model's output corresponds to the case of only one class, not three, so you should replace this line:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is now working fine-@Matias Valdenegro